# can't get JSON data with ng-for

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have JSON containing `Stores[]--->Products[]--->ProductDetails--->ProductTags[]` for the begining I want to see all the data
so I coded:

service

```
export class StoreService {
  //private myurl: string ="apidata/products.json"
  constructor(private _http: Http) {}
  getProducts(): Observable < any > {

    let apiUrl = './assets/products.json';
    return this._http.get(apiUrl)
      .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
        const data = response.json();
        return data;
      }));
  }
```

store component:

```
export class StoreComponent implements OnInit {
  products = [];

  constructor(private _storeService: StoreService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._storeService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.products = data;
        console.log(data)
      });
  }

}
```

html

```
<h2>store</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let p of products">{{p}}</li>
</ul>
```

the error I get:

> Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are
>   allowed

Comment: what the `console.log(data)` shows ?

Comment: Please include a sample of your JSON itself.

Comment: Seems like `data` is not a collection.

Comment: @selemmn [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owfMC.png)

Comment: @KirkLarkin its not letting me edit

Comment: @Kate check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally get this error when you pass an Object to `*ngFor` as an input. As the error states, `*ngFor` only works with Iteratable Data Structures, which in our case will be an array of products.

Make sure that in here: `this.products = data;`, `data` is actually an array.

#### UPDATE:

As it's quite obvious from this screenshot of the console log:

[image]

`data` is an object and not an array. `PriceFilter`, `Stores` and `GenderFilter` on that object are arrays. If you want to show `stores`, you can do:

```
export class StoreComponent implements OnInit {
  stores = [];

  constructor(private _storeService: StoreService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._storeService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.stores = data.Stores;
        console.log(data)
      });
  }

}
```

And in template

```
<h2>store</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let store of stores">
    <h4>Products:</h4>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let product of store.Products">
        <p>Product Id: {{ product.ProductId }}</p>
        <p>Product Title: {{ product.ProductTitle }}</p>
        ...
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I declared on  products as array

Comment: Thanks! now the error is gone but none data appears

Comment: Yes The first pic is the log of data

Comment: Checking. one min

Comment: [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/puucT.png)nice! thanks! so now how can I show the data but not like JSON (like regular details on site?

Comment: how can I get this way all the products? which inside stores

Comment: Thanks! best answer! how can I show this json like regular details of product?[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0ApP.png)

Comment: RIGHT. many thanks! last question, how to edit the list so the items will be near one each other?

Comment: That's something you'll have to implement using styles in css/scss. Also, I'd suggest not to ask so many questions as a part of a single question as it makes more noise than impact.If you have multiple questions, mention them upfront. If you'd have provided the complete `products.json` in the question, this would not have turned into such a big discussion. Just saying, in order to maintain the quality of a port, please mention everything upfront instead of asking them in bits and pieces.

Answer (score 1):

An error which you are getting suggests that your data is either an object / map instead of an array.

If you want to use *ngFor in your template, your data needs to be an array instead of an object.

Although angular team introduce a pipe called **"keyvalue"** in **version 6.1**. So you can take advantage of that and iterate over an object inside your angular template.

For example, assume that your object looks like below

```
const user = {
    name: 'xyz',
    age: 30,
    gender: 'male'
};
```

So in your template file, you can iterate over this object like this

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let data of user | keyvalue">
        Key : {{data.key}} and Value : {{data.value}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please refer [this link](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) for more info about this pipe

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of this error is that your `data` (products) is returning an object {} - ngFor requires an array [] to iterate. Either you have to check your HTTP Response or fix your backend API.

And merely for your example you can do this `this.products = data.Stores;` **(if it is *`stores`* is what you're looking for to iterate on)**.

---

**UPDATE**

According to your link in comments you have to change your code to :

```
this.products = data.Stores;
```

And then :

```
<div *ngFor="let p of products">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of p">
       <-- HERE you take whatever you want from your product object --!>
      </li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I am looking for products which inside stores

Comment: I do not get the point, could you do a `console.log(data.Stores)` ?